# Ensure a string contains specific characters, each at most once

Tags: php, regex

I would like to test if a string is empty or if it only contain specific characters, each at most once.

Example:

Given `$valid = 'ABCDE'`, the following strings are:

```
$a = ''; // valid, empty
$b = 'CE'; // valid, only contains C and E, each once
$c = 'AZ'; // invalid, contains Z
$d = 'DAA'; // invalid, contains A twice
```

Any quick way of doing this, (possibly) using regex?

Comment: Without regex it would much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using the following regex pattern:

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)[ABCDE]{0,5}$
```

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
^                    from the start of the string
    (?!.*(.).*\1)    assert that the same letter does not repeat
    [ABCDE]{0,5}     then match 0-5 letters
$                    end of the string
```

Sample PHP script:

```
$input = "ABCDE";
if (preg_match("/^(?!.*(.).*\1)[ABCDE]{0,5}$/", $input)) {
    echo "MATCH";
}
```

The negative lookahead `(?!.*(.).*\1)` works by checking if it can capture any single letter, and then also find it again later on in the string.  Let's take the OP's invalid input `DAA`.  The above negative lookahead would ffail when it matches *and* captures the first `A`, and then sees it again.  Note carefully that lookarounds can have their own capture groups.

Comment: What if $valid varible changes, ie it comes other than `ABCDE`

Comment: This is brilliant.

Comment: @Nicolas I also used that demo tool (initially), and it also had quirks.  But, it seems to be working in a [PHP demo](https://rextester.com/RDVX17981).

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail about the `(?!.*(.).*\1) ` expression and how using the negative look ahead you achieve that 'the same letter does not repeat'. Thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you please check this: https://rextester.com/RDVX17981 but when I test the pattern here https://regex101.com/ its working fine

Comment: @Akam The pattern seems to be working from PHP.  I don't know what the issue is with Regex101, though I will tell you that the only litmus test with which you should really be concerned is that it works from PHP.

Comment: I've read it, thanks. But why cant I use only `(?!(.*)\1)` ? why do I need to match everything before and after the capture group ? basically it says the match should not contain `'every char' zero or more times` then `every char single time` then `'every char' zero or more times` then `a reference to the single char`. I cant seem to understand the logic of that.

Comment: @Alon `(.*)` matches _multiple_ characters.  Also, we need to allow for a single character in any position being repeated.